# How to change table column nullable definition using declarative schema?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, db-schema

I have added a table using declarative schema given below:

```
<table name="trade_item_brand_category">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="item_pool" nullable="false" length="100" comment="Brand"/>
        <column xsi:type="datetime" name="new_brand_approved_time" on_update="false" nullable="false" comment="Brand Approval Time"/>
        
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
           <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
</table>
```

Now I  want to change `nullable` definition of `new_brand_approved_time` column from false to true. I have modified this db_schema.xml file as give below

```
 <column xsi:type="datetime" name="new_brand_approved_time" nullable="true" comment="Brand Approval Time"/>
```

After running `setup:upgrade` I am checking `new_brand_approved_time` field but `nullable` is still `false` for this column.

I have also tried the old M2 approach of UpgradeSchema as given below, still nullable option is not changing

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if ($installer->getConnection()->tableColumnExists('trade_item_brand_category', 'new_brand_approved_time')) {
            $definition = [
                'nullable' => true,
            ];
            $installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
                $setup->getTable('trade_item_brand_category'),
                'new_brand_approved_time',
                $definition
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When I run setup:upgrade, db_schema.xml file is being executed. I have testing it by adding a new column to the table but nullable option is not changing for column new_brand_approved_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update `setup_version` value in etc/module.xml for `UpgradeSchema` file to execute.

I have done below changes and ran setup:upgrade and it worked.

Updated setup_version from `1.0.0` to `1.0.1`

Updated db_schema as given below

```
<column xsi:type="datetime" name="new_brand_approved_time" nullable="true" comment="Brand Approval Time"/>
```

And updated UpgradeSchema as given below:

```
<?php

namespace Unioncoop\Tradeproducts\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if ($installer->getConnection()->tableColumnExists('trade_item_brand_category', 'new_brand_approved_time')) {
            $definition = [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                'nullable' => true
            ];
            $installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
                $setup->getTable('trade_item_brand_category'),
                'new_brand_approved_time',
                $definition
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue today too. Not sure why Magento 2 does not find the `nullable` attribute has been changed.

I fixed it by updating the `comment` attribute to something else and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated`.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate `whitelist.json` after changing db_schema

Using below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=YourModule_Name
```

Then check you etc folder if or not db_schema_whitelist.json is generated

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me. I have found the solution and added here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mix db_schema with setup script is a good idea.
Your problem maybe come from your data.

You can try run command for filling all data before re-change nullable

example  `update trade_item_brand_category set new_brand_approved_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where 1=1`

and then, change nullable to true and run s:up command

Hope it help!

Comment: Since nullable is false, all existing rows already has value for this column. Now I was trying to make nullable true, so that new rows which will be inserted can have null value.

Comment: yes, i understand. i tried with some field and it fine. Did you face any error when run s:up command

Comment: Nope. No error.